# How can I change text in a loop with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use HTML5/CSS to make text that will change using a list of available phrases.

As in at first it could say "Hello", and then it will change to say "Hello 2", etc.

Have looked up and reworded it many times, I can't seem to find anything for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Need more information. You want the text to change - what would trigger the change?

Comment: I just want for it to change automatically as long as they have the page open. No specific trigger, I just want it to change every 5 seconds or so to the next item in the list in a loop indefinitely.

Comment: CSS isn't the right tool for this. While it can be done, it's clumsy and inflexible. A simple JavaScript function would be much better.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment, I implements [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) that changes content of the element with every 5s.

If you want to add more detail on your animation, please check out [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

```css
@keyframes change-text {
  0% {
    content: "Hello";
  }
  33.33% {
    content: "Hello 2";
  }
  66.66% {
    content: "Hello 3";
  }
  100% {
    content: "Hello 4";
  }
}

.text-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.text {
  font-size: 2rem; 
}
.text::after {
  display: block;
  content: "Hello";
/* animation-duration = number of keyframes * duration per keyframe */
  animation: change-text 20s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.yourClass {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.yourClass:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "The world is so beautiful!";
}
```

```html
<div class="yourClass">Hello World!</div>
```